# Numpad not working even after changing different keyboards

Tags: numpad

My numpad of keyboard is not working in any way. I have tried several times by switching different key boards and switching among USB ports.

Comment: Not only is this off-topic, it's not even a question!

Comment: @Vicky It's a question brother someone facing the problem doesn't know the solution so he will ask question same goes with this guy.

Comment: @ShahAbdullah SO is for programming-related questions only.

Comment: @YuHao yes brother and keyboard needs to be working for programming isn't it funny  ? it's an essential question :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After Watching your question there could be two possibilities:

*Case 1:*

Your port isn't working properly. Have you tried switching keyboard to any other CPU?

If working.

then your port is malfunctioning.

If not working.

there could be fault in Keyboard.

*Case 2:*

May be you were accessing your mouse keys through Keyboard Numpad so that it behaves like mouse to undo it and make it work follow following steps:

Start-> Control Panel -> Ease of Access -> Change how your keyboard works -> uncheck TURN ON MOUSE KEY

after following above steps it will work for sure.

Comment: Thank You. Case 2 was mine. I use to keep mouse key ON that was the reason  faced this issue..

Comment: @AffanShahab No prob brother

Answer (score -2):

There's a key which turns on/off the Numpad. If it's still not working, smash your keyboard and get a new one (a decent keyboard with a Numpad).

Switching USB ports won't solve this issue. If you plug the keyboard in a USB port and the alphanumeric keys are working and you still have a problem with the Numpad, then the problem isn't related to the USB port.

Comment: Thank you dear but you answer was not help ful. Firstly NumLock key is an obvious thing, I definitely have checked it. And 2nd thing is that i already have mentioned i have switched multiple keyboards.. Any how i got my answer above.. Thank You all